# Free tool for Displaying MySQL Query Output in Graphical format

Tags: mysql, graph, charts, fusioncharts

I am looking for a Free tool that would display the output of MySQL query in a nice graphical format instantly.

I do not want to go through the manual process of saving in .csv or .xls and generating a graph in .xls . Looking for better/automated options - even if there are softwares with limited trial period, that would be appreciated.

Rgds

Comment: The question you ask does not have an answer, it has a many opinions. It also does not belong on a programming Q/A forum

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en

Comment: Let me also add that I do not want to write any code ....the tool should be more of a 'drag n display' type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dbForge Studio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/mysql-query-builder.html)

Another powerfull tool is [Flyspeed SQL Query](http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html)